# unit test $location.path().search method

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

I have a directive called clickElement:

```
 function clickElement( $location) {

            var clickElementDefinition = {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    clickElement: "="
                },
                link: clickElementMethod
            };
            return clickElementDefinition ;

            function clickElementMethod(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function (event) {
                        if (scope.clickElement) {
                        var arr = scope.clickElement.split("?");
                        var queryParam = arr[1].split("=") || "";
                        $location.path(arr[0]).search(queryParam[0], queryParam[1]);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

How do i unit test search method?

I have added spyOn path method :

```
spyOn($location, 'path').and.returnValue('/test/1');

expect($location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/test/1');
expect($location.search).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Make another spy on `search` method.

Comment: spyOn($location, 'search') , even after adding this i get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined